# Why isn't grub loading in UEFI?

Tags: linux, boot, grub, uefi, secure-boot

I'm stuck trying to get Linux to boot on my PCs. I've been trying a lot with OpenSUSE and Ubuntu on my different laptops but none of them work. Regardless how many times I run `update-grub`, it never runs.

Both of them have [MS signed *shim*s](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2951559/operating-systems/how-to-install-linux-on-a-pc-with-secure-boot-enabled.html) so the UEFI should load them properly, but in reality they're not, even though the `update-grub` or `grub2-install` outputs always say that grub has been installed successfully.

I have tried turning off secure boot and install grub again but still not working. I also turned off [fastboot, fast startup and Intel SRT](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI) but that doesn't help, either.

I tried `boot-repair` and not a single time any error appears. In the output log it says:

> If your computer reboots directly into Windows, try to change the boot order in your BIOS.
>
> If your BIOS does not allow to change the boot order, change the default boot entry of the Windows bootloader.
>
> For example you can boot into Windows, then type the following command in an admin command prompt:
>
> ```
> bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi
> ```

So there's no option to change boot order in UEFI settings, only boot device order like in BIOS and I have to run  the last command.

It works now but I don't want to chainload grub from Windows bootloader like that. I want to **load grub directly** because I want to run Linux alone in my new PC and run Windows only in a virtual machine. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: "bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi" changes NVRAM boot variable - this way you have a boot entry that points to "\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi". You don't need a Windows partition for this to function, but eventually leave "\EFI\Microsoft" on ESP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a uefi system, technically you don't need grub at all.

But to answer the question, it sounds like your UEFI implementation is very limited if you can't even change the boot target from the firmware boot-time options.

You can edit these options from Linux by using `efibootmgr`. Just set your grub efi as the first target, and if you've configured grub properly it should handle everything from there.

Answer (score 0):

I got issues with the clunky Acer's UEFI again. Somehow when I run `efibootmgr` to edit the boot items the changes can't be saved. After restarting everything was reset so I can't boot into Linux. I found [this working answer](https://forums.intel.com/s/question/0D50P000049093DSAQ/efi-boot-manager-ignores-menu-order-and-always-selects-to-load-windows-boot-manager?language=en_US) which renames the Microsoft folder and adds another entry

```
su -c 'cd /boot/efi/EFI && gzip /boot/efi/EFI/Microsoft'
su -c 'mkdir /boot/efi/EFI/1Microsoft && mkdir /boot/efi/EFI/1Microsoft/Boot && mv /boot/efi/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi /boot/efi/EFI/1Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi'
su -c 'efibootmgr -c -w -L Win7 -d /dev/sda -p 1 -l '\EFI\1Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi' -b 6'
```

That helps... until I update Windows. So I've been digging around and found another way.

During startup press <kbd>F2</kbd> to enter UEFI setup and switch to the Security tab. There you can see the *"Select an UEFI file as trusted for executing"* option. Press <kbd>enter</kbd> on it and select the efi file for the bootloader you want to use. Type the desire name, press *Yes* to confirm and that file will be added to the boot menu. Now you can switch to the Boot tab to change the order if you want. Or just press <kbd>F12</kbd> during startup to boot that menu

[image: Security tab]